# Openshift database gets truncated

Tags: openshift

I have two applications running on openshift. Currently, it is for test purposes only, but the intention is to run those apps on openshift for real later on. 
One thing that surprises me is that the data I enter gets deleted moreless regularly.
That is, when I return to the URL some days later, some tables are empty.
there are currently three developers and none of us did delete the data on purpose...

Does it have to do with our price plan? Is there any other explanation?
Any hints will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the log files?
OpenShift does not do anything that would truncate or touch your database. The only other explanation would be that you are out of disk space but then you would get an error message that you are out of space.

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide us with more detail then we might give you a better answer. What database gear are you using? Do you get any log messages? Does your data get successfully inserted into the table in the first place?

Openshift does not just go into your database gear and delete them, but until you can tell us more, we can't give you better answers.